# Isabelle definitions with subscripts

Tags: isabelle

I the `Tutorial on (Co)datatype Definitions` https://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2022/doc/datatypes.pdf
in `Introduction`
I see the definition

```
datatype 'a tree_fs = Node_fs (lbl_fs:'a) (sub_fs: “'a tree_fs fset ”)
```

where `_fs` are written in subscript. Then they are used  with different subscripts later on, suggesting that those subscripts are not merely a fancy design but can actually be "instantiated" in some sense. Where can I find more information about it and how can I use such subscripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those subscripts can be instantiated using the predefined symbol `\<^sub>`, which you can insert in Isabelle/JEdit by typing `\sub` (literally) and choosing the down arrow icon that shows up in the dropdown list. In the specific example you refer to, you need to include a subscript for each letter `f` and `s` individually, that is, `\<^sub>f\<^sub>s`.

You can read more about this in [The Isabelle/Isar Reference Manual](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2022/doc/isar-ref.pdf), Appendix A "*Predefined Isabelle symbols*".

Comment: IIRC the shortcut is C-e down-arrow. To ease typing there are also these abbreviation you can put in the header.